# Strange White stripe on right of the firefox browser window

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser

I've been using firefox for last 4years. But I'm in big trouble with this browser lately. A vertical white stripe showing right side of the browser. Not only stripe but also options shifted to left. Maybe my attached image could explain details:
[image]

I've uninstalled and installed firefox hundreds of time. Yes, of course I've removed all plugins and add-ons. Nothing worked. Please gimme a solution. :(

PS: I'm using Windows 7, firefox version 33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love Mozilla, I love Firefox support. **Got Solution!!!**

Here I'm sharing with you guys who is suffering from this problem:

- Press the `Shift` key while starting Firefox to enter  Safe Mode.
- If the problem does not occur in Safe Mode, turn off  hardware acceleration  and then start

To turn of Hardware Acceleration:

- Click the menu button and choose Options
- Select the Advanced panel and the General tab.
- Uncheck `Use hardware acceleration` when available.
- Click the menu button and then click Exit button.
- Start Firefox the way you normally do.

Here is the link where I got this support:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-shows-black-screen-or-blank-screen-after-u

Comment: Did turning off hardware acceleration work for you?

Comment: yes. are you still having this trouble?

Comment: Nope. I just wanted to make sure it worked for you :-)